Driving School in Berlin Cancelling Classes Frequently
I'm frustrated with my driving school. I signed up on April 2nd 2024 and paid for 10 classes in advance because they offered a good deal. By the way, they only accepted cash, just like most driving schools. Each class is supposed to be 80 minutes long.
But here's the problem:

In April, they gave me only 3 classes after many reschedules.

In May, they scheduled many classes, but again, all were canceled except for 3.

They promised no more cancellations, but this week, they canceled 2 out of my 3 classes again. So, I could only do 1 class.


When I asked to reschedule the canceled classes, they said I can have only 1 more class this month on June 28 (after 22 days).
The reception lady always cancels and reschedules on WhatsApp, which frustrates me. Out of the 6 classes I've taken so far, the driving instructor only completed the full 80 minutes twice. The other 4 times, the classes were only 60 minutes long.
They explained that they get exam dates from TÜV or DEKRA and must cancel classes if they clash with exams. But this happens all the time. Not once have I taken a class as planned. Even if there's a clash, they could offer a different time on the same day or another day, but they don't. They know how frustrated I am with them, but they simply don't care. They even ignore my follow-ups on class rescheduling.
How can I learn and practice if I don't have regular classes? By the time I had my next class, I had already forgotten what I had learned previously, and I had repeated the same mistakes. The driving instructor tells me the same mistakes again and again. If I had 1 class each day, I know in 2 weeks I could learn the driving rules properly. Just because I don't have the classes to practice, I can't improve. And in this way, it would take me 2-3 years to pass the exam.
I want to know:

Can I switch to a new driving school and ask them to consider the classes I already took?

Does switching make sense, or are all schools the same and have similar issues?

Has anyone else had a similar experience? What did you do? Should I keep following what the driving school says?


Thank you for any advice!

What research on driving schools (particularly on the one to whom you paid cash upfront) did you do before signing up? IDK about Germany but a business that only accepts cash is typically big red flag for me, especially if they want a large deposit or full payment upfront.

@Traveller Before this, I took a demo class with Orange Fahrschule, and they also only accepted cash. My impression is that there are fewer English-speaking driving schools, and they only take cash. They exploit expats, and of course, cash means no taxes. I don't know how to prove or report this. I'm new in Germany, so I don't speak German well enough to enroll in a German-speaking driving school.

What exactly is being cancelled? The group theory lessons, or your personal driving lessons?

@nvoigt Theory exam I have passed. I am learning the driving car now.

I’m voting to close this question because because it addresses the performance and behavior of a German driving school. The issue is not specific to expatriates, and could easily arise with a German citizen as well. Thus, the question is off-topic for Expatriates.SE which deals with challenges specific to expatriate status.

One option to consider is an intensive course eg.


Can I switch to a new driving school and ask them to consider the classes I already took?

Yes.
According to § 6 Ⅱ 3 FahrschAusbO you receive a document confirming the classes and driving lessons you have already completed (template) and the driving school can credit them.
Failing to issue a confirmation is an administrative offense, § 8 Ⅰ no. 7 FarschAusbO.
However, the driving instructor, the specific person, must be convinced of your capabilities, § 6 Ⅰ 1 FahrAusbO.
If you are short of one hour or two of being admitted to the final exam, do not expect the next driving school will be glad to give you the go‑ahead after completing these.

Does switching make sense, or are all schools the same and have similar issues?

Switching makes sense.
While there is a driving instructor shortage, the constant rescheduling is inappropriate and not in good faith, § 242 BGB.
Fun fact:
At no point the German law mandates that you have to take different theory lessons.
De jure you can attend 12 × 90 minute lessons listening to the same subject over and over again.

[…] By the way, they only accepted cash, just like most driving schools. […]

Like Traveller already wrote, in Germany businesses accepting cash only is a red flag (with the exception of transactions amounting to less than about €10).
It is certainly not forbidden, but if you pay in cash at least insist on a receipt, § 368 cl. 1 BGB.

[…] cash means no taxes. […]

Cash means no technically enforced paper trail.
It is still taxable income.
